# Where do System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache caching data

Tags: asp.net, caching, nopcommerce

Where do System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache cache/store data when it is Memorycahce.Default?

Do it save data in ram or cpu L1 cache ?

How do I caching memory in task manager?

Comment: what do you mean by "caching memory in task manager"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes those are in memory (OR) in-process cache and does store the data in server's memory (RAM) whether L1/L2 cache that no idea. So, in case your worker process goes off (OR) IIS recyles (with context of ASP.NET) then all your cached data is gone.

On the other hand, you can as well choose to use `distributed cache` mechanism like `REDIS` or `Azure Mem Cache` which are stored on separate server instance and not in your server process.

Comment: So if we save lots of CacheItem in memoryCache such as 1 million data and we do continuous writing and reading. Then will iis worker process take lots of resource of cpu?

Answer (score 0):

No, it has nothing to do with processor caches L1, L2 or others. It is just a caching (as a concept) solution ,that is being held in memory.

Comment: So if we save lots of CacheItem in memoryCache such as 1 million data and we do continuous writing and reading. Then will iis worker process take lots of resource of cpu?

Comment: You will incur a load on a CPU anyways, since you're intentionally reading/writing data, there's no DMA involved in this case AFAIK. Here however a CPU caching mechanism kicks in to try and improve data access speed.